# How can one check in PHP if a string can be converted into a whole number?

Tags: php

For instance, "000", "404", and "0523" can be converted into whole numbers in PHP, but "42sW" and "423 2343" cannot be converted into whole numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than just checking that every character in the string is a digit?

Comment: [Which definition of whole number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) are you thinking of?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `ctype_digit` function. `is_numeric` will also permit floating point values.

```
$numArray = array("1.23","156", "143", "1w");
foreach($numArray as $num)
{
    if (ctype_digit($num)) {
            // Your Convert logic
        } else {
            // Do not convert print error message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `ctype_digit` works great. `is_numeric` doesn't work since all rational numbers will work for is_numeric, but it's nice to know that function too, thanks!

Comment: @gus What are you trying to say.

Comment: If you do pass in int it will return false regardless if its a whole number. That may not be expected. Thought it worth mentioning, cheers.

Comment: $numArray = array("1.23",156, "143", "1w"); 1.23 false *156 false* 143 true 1w false

Comment: @David Faux: 1.2e2 is a "whole number" but will will fail the ctype,_digit() test.

Answer (score 9):

PHP's `is_numeric()` can determine if a given param is a number or a number *string*.  Have a read through the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) for some examples.

Comment: This will be true for things like '1.5'

Answer (score 2):

[`ctype_digit`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

42Sw can be converted to a number by using intval()

```
      echo intval("42sW"); // prints 42
```

Answer (score 1):

use `is_numeric()`:

```
if (is_numeric("string")) {
    echo "This can be converted to a number";
}
```

Comment: This will be true for things like '1.5'

Comment: @galdikas and? isn't 1.5 a number?

Comment: @clockw0rk depending on the use case it might be ok or not. I did have once a case where I specifically needed to determine if a string is integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($string)) {
//functions here
}
else{
//functions2 here
}
?>
```

Comment: This will be true for things like '1.5'

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "42sW";
if (ctype_digit($test)) {
        echo "The string $test consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $test does not consist of all digits.\n";
    }

//OR
is_numeric($test);   // false
```

Comment: Wouldn't `is_numeric()` return true for non-whole numbers as well (1.23)?